# How do I overwrite specific items in my List<object>

Tags: c#

I have a list of items that have certain values. As my list is passed along in code those values may need to be changed.  I understand Insert and Add but is there some method or technique to Update or InsertAt?

Comment: There is `Insert(int index, T item)` in a `List`, not `InsertAt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to replace the reference just assign it.

```
list[index] = new Item();
```

If you need to update a property on that item, you need to cast it.

```
var item = list[index] as Item;
item.Foo = bar;
```

I would strongly suggest that you use the specific type for the generic list - so `List<Item>` , and you shouldn't need to cast items coming out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use indexer with list to access particular item

```
var item = list[0];
```

To change item in list

```
list[0] = someobject;
```

Suppose we have list of strings

```
 List<string> lst = new List<string>();
 lst.Add("Hello");
 lst[0] = "Change hello";
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you just want to change the item at a given index. Use the assignment operator on that index like;

```
   list[index] = MyOtherReferenceOfListsType;
```